# Does FPGA performance reduce after multiple cycles of reprogramming?

Tags: hardware, fpga, cpu-architecture

Does FPGA performance (max stable clock speed) reduce after many cycles of programming?

Comment: This question seems oddly specific to me. Why do you think it would? And what exactly do you mean by "performance"?

Comment: You mean max stable clock speed?  I'd guess the rated max speed has some headroom for wear, if wear makes anything slower.  I could also imaging the time to re-program might get worse, like with flash memory, if FPGAs use similar storage cells.

Comment: @Taschi Well, it is kinda specific. I'm not really familiar with the process of restructuring an FPGA for a new process but I was suspecting that over time and over many cycles of restructuring (say tens of thousands), it might affect the overall performance of the part.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't think that FPGA reprogramming is as quite similar to a Microcontroller programming because it involves manipulating the very fabric of FPGA. Yes as performance I mean the maximum clock speed that the part can handle.

Comment: Most FPGAs are SRAM based, hence there are no limitations on programming cycles. This may be a different story for the flash based ones.

Comment: Yeah, "restructuring" is really not the right word and makes the rewriting of a FPGA sound a lot more intrusive than it actually is. I don't have much of a clue about FPGAs (and I really should change that soon) but it seems to me that you shouldn't really need to be concerned about this.

Comment: @ARK1375: My understanding is that part of how FPGAs work is by table lookup of a truth table; that's how you choose what kind of gate it is.  Making or breaking a connection might also be as simple as programming a truth-table to be always-true or always-false, instead of dependent on the result from another cell.  (A 1-input truth table is very compact)

Comment: If a given FPGA has a limit to reliable write-cycles, then odds are it is also mentioned somewhere in the documentation. IC manufacturers are *incredibly* thorough with that kind of information.

Comment: @Taschi I looked it up, they don't have write-cycle limitation. So this resolves it. There is no evidence that indicates a speed decay for many reprogramming cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the technology of your FPGA.

There are 3 technologies available:

Antifuse:
Can be programmed only once, so I think you are not talking about them.

Flash:
As Every flash, the number or reprogram is finite, but until it stops to work (aka can't write the flash), there is no degradation of speed

SRAM:
This one can be "infinitely" re-programed. Now as every electronic component, it will decay with time and overheating, but it is not really related to the reprogrammation

ref: https://www.eetimes.com/all-about-fpgas/#